# iterate through array and compare to entity object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to get the various items in a one to many relationship of database objects.  So I have the entity framework create my locations object and one column in the table has a comma separated list of services available at a location.  I use:

```
var data = pubDB.Locations.Include("Branch_Ameneties");
```

in the model to get the relationsihp between a the two tables.  Then in the view I am trying to iterate through the features in an array and get the associated Branch Amenities:

```
@foreach (var Location in Model.LocationListings())
{
@if (Location.Features != null)
                {
                    string[] featureset = Location.Features.Split(',');
                    foreach (var item in featureset)
                    {
                        var feature = Location.Branch_Ameneties.Amenity.Where(x => Location.Branch_Ameneties.FID = Convert.ToInt32(item);
                        @feature
                    }
                }
```

And I can't seem to get the array to associate with the reference table of amentiites.

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the where clause, try using:

```
  var feature = Location.Branch_Ameneties.Amenity.Single(x => Location.Branch_Ameneties.FID == Convert.ToInt32(item));
```

Also, you had "..FID = Convert.ToInt32(item)" instead of "..FID **==** Convert..."